# Convert numeric String to its ASCII number

Tags: java, string, char

I have a `String` containing an ASCII digit character. I'd like to convert it to its ASCII-code as an `int`, so the `charAt`-method does not work directly here.

E.g. I have `String number = "4";`, how do I get its ASCII code (52) into an `int`?

Comment: Could you provide the code you have so far, and a clear statement of input/expected output?

Comment: what you mean by "does not work"?

Answer (score 0):

You need the typecast the character to integer.

```
String name = "a"; 
char character = name.charAt(0); 
int ascii = (int) character;
```

Comment: While this probably what the asker wants, it is misleading to call the number "ascii". It is ASCII in a roundabout way: `charAt` returns the Unicode/UTF-16 code unit from the string at the specified position. The Unicode characters (from a Java `String`) in question are encoded as only one UTF-16 code unit so taking one UTF-16 code unit gives the same integer as the Unicode codepoint. The characters in question are also in the ASCII character set. They have the same integer value as they do as ASCII. A code comment could clear this up.